# Javascript Parsing Key Value String to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently working on trying to create a UDF to split a key value pair string based on web traffic into JSON.

I've managed to get as far as outputting a JSON object but I'd like to be able to dynamically add nested items based on the number of products purchased or viewed based on the index number of the key.

When a product is only viewed, there is always only one product in the string. Only when its a transaction is it more than one but I think it would be good to conform the structure of the json and then identify a purchase or view based on the presence of a transactionid. For example:

Item Purchased:

```
sessionid=12345&transactionid=555555&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3&transactionamount=58
```

The output should look something like this:

```
[
   {
      "sessionid":12345,
      "transactionid":555555,
      "transactionamount":58
   },
   [
      {
         "productline":1,
         "product":"apples",
         "productprice":12,
         "productqty":1
      },
      {
         "productline":2,
         "product":"pears",
         "productprice":23,
         "productqty":2
      }
   ]
]
```

Item Viewed:

sessionid=12345&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3

```
[
   {
      "sessionid":12345,
      "transactionid":0,
      "transactionamount":0
   },
   [
      {
         "productline":1,
         "product":"apples",
         "productprice":12,
         "productqty":1
      }
   ]
]
```

The result I'll be able to parse from JSON into a conformed table in a SQL table.

What I've tried so far is only parsing the string, but its not ideal to create a table in SQL because the number of purchases can vary:

```
var string = "sessionid=12345&transactionid=555555&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3&transactionamount=58";

function splitstring(queryString) {
    var dictionary = {};

    if (queryString.indexOf('?') === 0) {
        queryString = queryString.substr(1);
    }

    var parts = queryString.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var p = parts[i];
        // Step 2: Split Key/Value pair
        var keyValuePair = p.split('=');
        var key = keyValuePair[0];
        var value = keyValuePair[1];

        dec_val = decodeURIComponent(value);
        final_value = dec_val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        dictionary[key] = final_value;
    }

    return (dictionary);
}

console.log(splitstring(string));
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: is this in browser code?

Comment: no, it wont be used in the browser

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a far nicer way to do this, but I just wrote code as I thought about it

```js
var string = "sessionid=12345&transactionid=555555&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3&transactionamount=58";

function splitstring(queryString) {
    var dictionary = {};

    if (queryString.indexOf('?') === 0) {
        queryString = queryString.substr(1);
    }

    var parts = queryString.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var p = parts[i];
        // Step 2: Split Key/Value pair
        var keyValuePair = p.split('=');
        var key = keyValuePair[0];
        var value = keyValuePair[1];

        dec_val = decodeURIComponent(value);
        final_value = dec_val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
        dictionary[key] = final_value;
    }

    return (dictionary);
}

function process(obj) {
    let i = 1;
    const products = [];
    while(obj.hasOwnProperty(`product${i}`)) {
        products.push({
            [`product`]: obj[`product${i}`],
            [`productprice`]: obj[`productprice${i}`],
            [`productqty`]: obj[`product${i}qty`]
        });
        delete obj[`product${i}`];
        delete obj[`productprice${i}`];
        delete obj[`product${i}qty`];
        ++i;
    }
    return [obj, products];
}
console.log(process(splitstring(string)));
```

By the way, if this is in the browser, then `splitstring` can be "replaced" by

```
const splitstring = string => Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(string).entries());
```

```js
var string = "sessionid=12345&transactionid=555555&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3&transactionamount=58";

function process(string) {
  const splitstring = queryString => {
    var dictionary = {};

    if (queryString.indexOf('?') === 0) {
      queryString = queryString.substr(1);
    }

    var parts = queryString.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var p = parts[i];
      // Step 2: Split Key/Value pair
      var keyValuePair = p.split('=');
      var key = keyValuePair[0];
      var value = keyValuePair[1];

      dec_val = decodeURIComponent(value);
      final_value = dec_val.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
      dictionary[key] = final_value;
    }

    return (dictionary);
  };

  let i = 1;
  const obj = splitstring(string);
  const products = [];
  while (obj.hasOwnProperty(`product${i}`)) {
    products.push({
      [`product`]: obj[`product${i}`],
      [`productprice`]: obj[`productprice${i}`],
      [`productqty`]: obj[`product${i}qty`]
    });
    delete obj[`product${i}`];
    delete obj[`productprice${i}`];
    delete obj[`product${i}qty`];
    ++i;
  }
  return [obj, products];
}
console.log(process(string));
```

Comment: ^^ this is great, is it possible to wrap it all in one function?

Answer (score 0):

Feel like this would be less clunky with better param naming conventions, but here's my take...

```
function parseString(string) {
    var string = string || '',
        params, param, output, i, l, n, v, k, pk;
    params = string.split('&');
    output = [{},
        []
    ];
    for (i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
        param = params[i].split('=');
        n = param[0].match(/^product.*?([0-9]+).*/);
        v = decodeURIComponent(param[1] || '');
        if (n && n[1]) {
            k = n[1];
            output[1][k] = output[1][k] || {};
            output[1][k]['productline'] = k;
            pk = n[0].replace(/[0-9]+/, '');
            output[1][k][pk] = v;
        } else {
            output[0][param[0]] = v;

        }
    }
    output[1] = output[1].filter(Boolean);
    return output;
}

var string = "sessionid=12345&transactionid=555555&product1=apples&productprice1=12&product1qty=1&product2=pears&productprice2=23&product2qty=3&transactionamount=58";
console.log(parseString(string));
```

**output:**

```
[
    {
        "sessionid": "12345",
        "transactionid": "555555",
        "transactionamount": "58"
    },
    [{
        "productline": "1",
        "product": "1",
        "productprice": "12"
    }, {
        "productline": "2",
        "product": "3",
        "productprice": "23"
    }]
]
```